# spoj or codechef format command line input in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am new to programming and trying to start on platforms like spoj or codechef.
can anyone please help me in getting the input in this way

Input

The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Output

For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

i know how to split lines and extract int from there,but the thing i dont know is how to prompt for t number of lines .

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. They are passed to `stdin` of your program and you just read them without any prompt. Those systems handle your program automatically, so there is no need to display fancy prompt :).

```
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

# parse the input:
# number of cases
t = int(lines[0])
...
```